# iOS: force open 'safari window' fromout htmlpage

Tags: ios, html, safari

I would like to to know how a link on our webpage could open 'safari' (complete new window). What command do we have to implement in our Html5 jquery mobile page, that an iOS user clicks on this link and than the Safari browset will open en rdirect.ro a webpage?

The iOS hotspot log in window opens our guest log in page, from here we would like to open safari browser en redirect to a webpage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JSBridgeWebView Library

http://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/

Through this lib you can send message to an iOS app and then based on this message app will open Safari.

Comment: Could you privide me an example/script to use this?

Comment: There are clear instructions. if you visit above mentioned link then you'll see step-by-step instruction of how to use this library. They also have a sample xCode project for help.